# Solving Second Ordinary Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would we find the general formula for the following Differential equation using undetermined coefficients method or any other method you may know of.

$$y''-y=\cos x+\sin x $$

Thank you☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution by Laplace Transform:

$$y'' - y = cosx +sinx$$

$$\mathcal{L}(y'') - \mathcal{L}(y) = \frac{s}{s^2 +1} + \frac{1}{s^2 +1}$$

$$\mathcal{L}(y)=\frac{A}{2}(\frac{1}{s+1} + \frac{1}{s-1}) + \frac{B}{2}(\frac{1}{s-1} - \frac{1}{s+1}) + \frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s-1)}$$

$$\mathcal{L}(y)=\frac{A}{2}(\frac{1}{s+1} + \frac{1}{s-1}) + \frac{B}{2}(\frac{1}{s-1} - \frac{1}{s+1}) -\frac{(s+1)}{2(s^2 +1)} + \frac{1}{2(s-1)}$$

$$y=k_1 e^x +k_2 e^{-x} -\frac{cosx}{2} - \frac{sinx}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-y=\cos x+\sin x $$
The polynomial characteristic is :
$$r^2-1=0 \implies r=\pm 1$$
The solution to the homogeneous euation is :
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$
For the particular solution, use method of undetermined coefficients and try:
$$y_p=A\cos x +B \sin x$$

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Dawn you're welcome.

Comment: @Aryadeva I seem to be getting an additional term of $-\frac{cosx}{2}$ when I tried the same using Laplace Transform......I most probably have made a mistake as i am new to Laplace transforms

Comment: Check your answer because the guess works fine... @SaketGurjar you should get for the particular solution $y_p=−\frac12(\cos x +\sin x)$

Comment: @Aryadeva the general solution i am getting is $y=k_1 e^x + k_2 e^{-x} -\frac{cosx}{2} - \frac{sinx}{2}$ .....I checked thrice and also its satisfying the given equation.

Comment: Thats the solution indeed @SaketGurjar And thats what i wrote in my answer too. I don't really understand what the problem is.